How can change the size of hAxis labels in BarChart of Google Charts
In the BarChart component of Google Charts, I am unable to modify the size of the labels on my graph.
I am extracting a long text from the db that I want to display on the left side. So, I want to adjust the label size to display the entire message on the vertical axis.
Like this post (but increase) : Google chart decrease Y axis labels width
Can you help ?


set option chartArea.left to a value that allows the label to be displayed
